# Just typing Import[] tries to list folders in a directory, and it is slow over sshfs

Tags: performance-tuning, front-end, import, internals

It appears that Mathematica tries to list the folder that you're typing into an `Import[]` statement. Since I'm working with folders mounted over sshfs and they contain a lot of files, this can hang the frontend for quite a while. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: A quick and dirty solution is to first put the folder name into a string, and then once that is typed, add the `Import` around that. You can also block the autocomplete features. [Here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12406)

Comment: You should probably report this to Wolfram Support. It sounds like a "bug".  They may not have anticipated that folder lookup can take long. In principle, lookup could be done asynchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the option `"FileCompleteEnable"` to `False`, either for the notebook or globally. In the Option browser, it is under *Editing Options > Private... > CodeAssistOptions*.

Reference: [CodeAssistOptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CodeAssistOptions.html)